# Installing Xcode command line tools on M1 Mac after upgrading to macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, install, xcode, ventura

How to install Xcode command line tools on M1 Mac after upgrading to macOS Ventura?

I have tried the directions here: [Install Xcode Command Line Tools Directly · Mac Install Guide](https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/4.html), which incorrectly say to use: `xcode-select –install` (should be 2 dashes, not 1, before install).

Comment: What have you tried (e.g. using the App Store to download/install Xcode), how did it fail to work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Terminal, type:

```
xcode-select --install
```

This opens a window with a prompt. Follow the prompts. It then takes about 10 min to install.

**Confirm that Xcode is installed:**

Any of these methods will work:

```
pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | grep version
# version: 14.2.0.0.1.1668646533
```

or

```
xcode-select -p
# /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

or

```
gcc --version
# Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
# Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
# Thread model: posix
# InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```